# Integrating Google jib with yGuard

Tags: java, jib, yguard, maven-jib

Is there a way to obfuscate exploded/packaged output of jib-maven-plugin with yGuard (or some other obfuscator)?

I can think of a way using other tools such as exec-maven-plugin + jib cli.

Another possible way can be to devise a 3rd party jib-extension or even fork/hack jib-maven-plugin all together.

Maybe someone can share their experience with that.

For context I am trying to ship a Spring Boot application build using Maven and AntRun for yGuard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out myself.

Here is my exec-maven-plug + jib cli solution for anyone out there.

To test paste it, adapt it to your environment, and run `mvn clean package -P local`.

This `pom.xml` is from a multi-module setup, so you may have to refactor or omit the `<parent></parent>` tag to suit you needs.

**What it does:**

- Cleans target directory
- Compiles your source files into the target directory
- Obfuscates classes in the target directory
- Repackages classes, libs, resources in **exploded** form (for better layer caching) correctly into Spring Boot's non-standard `BOOT-INF` output directory
- Performs `docker build`, `docker push` under the hood through jib cli
- Performs `docker pull` at the end (for debug purposes)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>redacted</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.redacted</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>sm-test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <name>test</name>
  <description>test</description>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <profile.name>default</profile.name>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <mainClass>com.redacted.smtest.SmTestApplication</mainClass>
    <java.server.user>0:0</java.server.user>
    <java.to.image.tag>ghcr.io/redacted/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}-${profile.name}</java.to.image.tag>
    <java.from.image.tag>openjdk:11.0.14-jre@sha256:e2e90ec68d3eee5a526603a3160de353a178c80b05926f83d2f77db1d3440826</java.from.image.tag>
    <java.from.classpath>../target/${project.name}/${profile.name}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</java.from.classpath>
  </properties>

  <profiles>

    <!-- local -->
    <profile>
      <id>local</id>
      <properties>
        <profile.name>local</profile.name>
      </properties>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>noTest</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>jib jar</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <executable>jib</executable>
                  <workingDirectory>.</workingDirectory>
                  <skip>false</skip>
                  <arguments>
                    <argument>jar</argument>
                    <argument>--mode=exploded</argument>
                    <argument>--target=${java.to.image.tag}</argument>
                    <argument>--from=${java.from.image.tag}</argument>
                    <argument>--user=${java.server.user}</argument>
                    <argument>--creation-time=${maven.build.timestamp}</argument>
                    <argument>--jvm-flags=-Xms32m,-Xmx128m,-Dspring.profiles.active=default</argument>
                    <argument>${java.from.classpath}</argument>
                  </arguments>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>docker pull</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <executable>docker</executable>
                  <workingDirectory>.</workingDirectory>
                  <skip>false</skip>
                  <arguments>
                    <argument>pull</argument>
                    <argument>${java.to.image.tag}</argument>
                  </arguments>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

  </profiles>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.yworks</groupId>
      <artifactId>yguard</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    <directory>../target/${project.name}/${profile.name}/</directory>
    <outputDirectory>../target/${project.name}/${profile.name}/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>obfuscate</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>false</skip>
              <tasks>

                <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                <taskdef name="yguard" classname="com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask" classpath="${runtime_classpath}"/>

                <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/obfuscated"/>

                <yguard>

                  <inoutpair in="${project.build.directory}/classes"
                             out="${project.build.directory}/obfuscated"/>

                  <externalclasses>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <pathelement path="${runtime_classpath}"/>
                  </externalclasses>

                  <rename mainclass="${mainClass}"
                          logfile="${project.build.directory}/rename.log.xml"
                          scramble="true"
                          replaceClassNameStrings="true">

                    <property name="error-checking" value="pedantic"/>
                    <property name="naming-scheme" value="best"/>
                    <property name="language-conformity" value="compatible"/>
                    <property name="overload-enabled" value="true"/>

                    <!-- Generated by sm-test -->
                    <map>
                      <class map="d1e6064d$5a15$449b$a632$b2d967a61021" name="com.redacted.smtest.YGuardMappingRunner"/>
                    </map>

                  </rename>

                </yguard>

                <delete dir="${project.build.directory}/classes/com"/>

                <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/com/" overwrite="true">
                  <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/obfuscated/com/" includes="**"/>
                </copy>

                <delete dir="${project.build.directory}/obfuscated"/>

              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Here is an associate `jib.yaml` file for `jib cli` to work:

```yaml
apiVersion: jib/v1alpha1
kind: BuildFile

workingDirectory: "/app"

entrypoint: ["java","-cp","/app/resources:/app/classes:/app/libs/*"]

layers:
  entries:
    - name: classes
      files:
        - properties:
            filePermissions: 755
          src: /classes
          dest: /app/classes
```

I also had to write a small throw-away class to generate custom mapping for unique class and package names for yGuard (apparently it cannot manage to do it on its own):

```java
package com.redacted.smtest;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.UUID;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class YGuardMappingRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    if (args == null || args.length == 0)
      return;

    generateYGuardMapping(Path.of(args[0]));
  }

  void generateYGuardMapping(Path path) throws IOException {
    var packageSb = new StringBuilder();
    var classSb = new StringBuilder();

    mapPackages(path, packageSb);
    mapClasses(path, classSb);

    if (packageSb.length() > 0 && classSb.length() > 0)
      log.info(
          "\n<!-- Generated by sm-test -->\n<map>\n{}\n{}</map>",
          packageSb.toString(),
          classSb.toString());
    else if (packageSb.length() > 0 && classSb.length() == 0)
      log.info("\n<!-- Generated by sm-test -->\n<map>\n{}</map>", packageSb.toString());
    else if (packageSb.length() == 0 && classSb.length() > 0)
      log.info("\n<!-- Generated by sm-test -->\n<map>\n{}</map>", classSb.toString());
  }

  private void mapClasses(Path path, StringBuilder classSb) throws IOException {
    try (var stream = Files.walk(path, Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
      stream
          .distinct()
          .filter(o -> o.getNameCount() >= 12)
          .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
          .map(o -> o.subpath(8, o.getNameCount()))
          .map(o -> o.toString().replace("\\", ".").replace(".java", ""))
          .filter(o -> !o.contains("Sm"))
          .sorted()
          .forEach(
              o ->
                  classSb.append(
                      String.format("%2s<class map=\"%s\" name=\"%s\"/>%n", "", getRandStr(), o)));
    }
  }

  private void mapPackages(Path path, StringBuilder packageSb) throws IOException {
    try (var stream = Files.walk(path, Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
      stream
          .map(Path::getParent)
          .distinct()
          .filter(o -> o.getNameCount() >= 12)
          .map(o -> o.subpath(8, o.getNameCount()))
          .map(o -> o.toString().replace("\\", "."))
          .sorted()
          .forEach(
              o ->
                  packageSb.append(
                      String.format(
                          "%2s<package map=\"%s\" name=\"%s\"/>%n", "", getRandStr(), o)));
    }
  }

  private String getRandStr() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("[-]+", "\\$");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify your yGuard configuration a bit by removing the `<shrink>` section. Since you explicitly keep all classes and all methods, there is not much shrink can do.

Comment: @Thomas Behr, yea you are right.